# a c computation

Tags: c

There must be some logic behind this calculation. But I am not able to get it.  The normal mathematics does not result in such behavior.  Can anyone help me out in explaining why

`printf ("float %f \n", 2/7 * 100.0);`  results in printing 1.000000

Why so?  I am not understanding the reason

Comment: I doubt it. It should print 0.0, since 2/7 = 0 (two as an integer goes 0 times in seven).

Comment: This should give 0.0; see e.g. http://ideone.com/V661TJ.

Comment: It should also print float in front of the number, make sure you pulled the correct line of output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Integer division. `2/7 = 0` as an integer, `0 * 100.0 = 0.0` as a float.

Do `2.0/7 * 100.0` to get the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Like my comment above, 2/7 is zero, always.

Comment: @MatsPetersson True, I meant to write 0. But i was copying the OP's code and forgot :\